# How can I use Google API to obtain the Geolocation of an IP address?

Tags: geolocation, ip-address

I'm looking for a free service for locating an IP Address getting its City, Country, Latitude and Longitude. I [believe](http://www.nitinh.com/2009/04/ip-address-geolocation-javascript-api-json/) that I can get the geo-location of an IP using the Google API. Has anyone done that before? Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this: http://isithackday.com/hacks/geo/yql-geo-library/ for my fallback when a device does not have GPS.

Best,

T